# Compiling a .c file using gimptool

Tags: c, math, linker, gimp

I've found a gimp plugin on GitHub that I'd like to use:
https://github.com/possiblyphilip/Koi (check it out, seems pretty cool).

But when I try to install it as the author suggests:

```
sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev
sudo gimptool-2.0 --install-admin Koi.c
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccaaHhWn.o: undefined reference to symbol 'cos@@GLIBC_2.0'
//lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix this? I've done some googling and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809404/issue-with-simple-makefile-undefined-reference-to-symbol-cosglibc-2-2-5) answer, suggesting that the error is caused by a missing math library which should be added in the linking stage (-lm). The problem however is that gimptool does everything automatically and I don't think there's a way to tell it to add anything.

The author of the plugin says that a prebuilt binary is also available, but it is nowhere to be found. I've e-mailed the guy, but he didn't answer yet.

If it's too obvious - I'm sorry, I just can't figure it out.

PS Nevermind - I've managed to install it using

```
sudo CC=gcc CFLAGS=-O3 LIBS=-lm gimptool-2.0 --install-admin Koi.c
```